# angular 2: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParent' of null

Tags: angular

All of a sudden this error occurs in my component:

"Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'setParent' of null"

I will try to reproduce in a plunkr, in the meantime maybe someone can throw me some hints?

Comment: I think until you create plunkr this question will be on hold

Comment: is there a way I can get the stacktrace outside the promise? Promises completly hide away any stacktrace as it seems...

Answer (score 7):

Solved it:

I was switching from a model-driven form to a template-driven form. I missed to remove one occurance of a "formControlName" on an input-element.

The "formControlName" on the input-element referenced a formControl that did not exist anymore on the component.

Comment: I am getting a similar error (after upgrading from angular2.RC4 to angular2.RC5). Do you have any tricks for diagnosing this error?

Comment: @brando : have u got any soultion for this ?

Comment: great answer, really needed to clean up my formControls

Answer (score 0):

Tobias answer might solve most of the issues, but in case you are still stuck, make sure you have a similar structure:

`File.ts`

```js
  // FORM
  selectedModeFormControl: FormControl;
  form: FormGroup;
  selectedMode: any;


 createForm(): void {
    this.selectedModeFormControl = new FormControl('');

    this.form = new FormGroup({
      selectedMode: this.selectedModeFormControl,
    });
  }
```

`File.html`

```html
 <form name="filters" [formGroup]="form">
    <input (...) formControlName="selectedMode"> ....
 </form>
```